# Replace all root div elements with spans in DraftJS?

Tags: html, reactjs, draftjs

Let me preface by saying this is NOT about the draftjs contents, solutions involving block render map will probably not work.

I have two elements next to each other in spans, I want the second element to be a draftjs editor - it CANNOT rely on grids or flexboxes or tables.

DraftJS stores elements in nested divs, I found if I override those divs to spans I get the desired outcome:
[image: l,]

My question is, how can I do this programatically (if at all) - do I have other options?

Answer (score 2):

divs are block-level elements while spans are inline elements. If you can select the divs you want to display as spans and change their display style to be `display: inline;` , that should do the trick.

```
const elem = document.getElementsByClassName("DraftEditor-root");
elem[0].style.display = "inline";
```